# passing array from one function to the other

Tags: c++

I think I've got my self confused by following codes. Suppose I have two simple functions:

```
int* makeiniele()
{
    int res[55] = { 0 };
    return res;
}
```

and

```
void printele(int* wxyz)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 55; k++)
    {
        cout << wxyz[k] << "\n";
    }
}
```

The problem is when I run the following line:

```
printele(makeiniele());
```

I get 55 big negative numbers instead of 55 zeros!

Thank you for your time

Comment: Only with a pointer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

1) The array is not initialized to contain 55 zeros, but only 1, remaining 54 elements are going to be some older memory content:

```
int res[55] = { 0 };
```

you need to use the `memset()` function in order to do that efficiently:

```
int res[55];
memset(res, 0, sizeof(res));
```

2) The array you declare in the `makeiniele()` function will be deallocated after returning from the function and (since it was living on the stack) its content is going to be overwritten by the call of next function `printele()`. Therefore, initializing it correctly won't fix your problems.

A solution would be to consider using `malloc()` to allocate the array instead. Your `makeiniele()` function should look like this:

```
int* makeiniele(){
  int *res = malloc(sizeof(int)*55));
  memset(res, 0, sizeof(int)*55);
  return res;
}
```

And remember to call `free()` after you have finished with the array in order to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks, Now I got it. Just one thing: I just checked it; when I initialize first element to something ,c++ set the others to zero.

Comment: I don't think so. That would happen if you use one of the C++'s container types like `std::vector`, `std::array`. But I  am pretty sure C++ does nothing in particular (regarding initialization) when using C arrays (like in your example).
Unless you do the array allocation as a `static`, in that case the standard guarantees to be 0 initialized.

Comment: I see. One other question:when I'm using functions in this manner printele(makeiniele()) , how can I free memory for allocated memory in makeiniele?

Comment: Well, you can't. You can however call `free()` inside the print function after having printed its elements (given nobody else is going to need the array).

Comment: Since this question is tagged [tag:c++] I would suggest using `new`/`delete` instead of `malloc`/`free`. Or even using `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`

Answer (score 0):

```
int* makeiniele()
{
    int res[55] = { 0 };
    return res;
}
```

The problem here lies with *scope* - once a function ends, any variables declared within the function are deleted from memory. Once the function `makeiniele` terminates, the array `res` is also deleted from memory. The memory that array took up has been replaced with something else - this 'something else' is what's being printed to your screen. You can verify this with the following code:

```
int * myvar = new int[55]{ 0 };
int* var = myvar;
printele(var);
delete myvar;
printele(var);
```

The fist 55 numbers will be zeroes (the variable hasn't been deleted yet). Once the variable is manually deleted with `delete` the address of it is now pointing to unused memory, so it spits out random numbers. To fix this, replace your `makeiniele` funciton with this:

```
int* makeiniele()
{
    int * myvar = new int[55]{ 0 };
    return myvar;
}
```

And everything should work fine!

EDIT: As Zereges said, you MUST ensure to end your program with

```
delete myvar;
```

to prevent a memory leak.

Comment: Except for the part with memleak.

Comment: @Zereges I'll add a delete, thanks

Answer (score 0):

A little modern C++ answer.

Either using clever array ([`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/))

```
std::vector<int> makeiniele()
{
    std::vector<int> res(55, 0);
    return std::move(res);
}

void printele(const std::vector<int>& wxyz)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 55; k++)
    {
        cout << wxyz[k] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Or using clever pointers ([`std::shared_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/))

```
std::shared_ptr<int> makeiniele()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> res(new int[55]);
    std::memset(res.get(), 0, 55 * sizeof(int));
    return std::move(res);
}

void printele(std::shared_ptr<int> wxyz)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 55; k++)
    {
        std::cout << wxyz.get()[k] << "\n";
    }
}
```